# iTunesConnect: "One or more of your app previews could not be loaded. Try again."

Tags: ios, video, video-processing, appstore-approval

#### Problem

Recently I uploaded App preview video to my app in iTunesConnect

It looks like it was uploaded successfully, I was able to play it but there was a text overlay on the video preview:

```
Processing App Preview

The app preview can take up to 24 hours to process.
```

[image: Processing App Preview The app preview can take up to 24 hours to process.]

I have closed Safari and go to sleep. Next morning I see this

[image: One or more of your app previews could not be loaded. Try again.]

#### Questions

1. How can I get a reason why this happens, as far as I see my video conform to https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev4e413fcb8 , here is `ffprobe` output for it

   ```js
   ffprobe version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
     built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
     configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
     libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
     libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
     libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
     libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
     libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
     libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
     libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
     libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
     libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
   Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/camobap/my_video.mp4':
     Metadata:
   major_brand     : isom
   minor_version   : 512
   compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
   encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
     Duration: 00:00:30.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1512 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 886x1920, 1377 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
   Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
   Metadata:
     handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
   ```
2. Who actually does this video review? Humans or machines?
3. Is there any automation script to do this validation before upload?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Silly me, looks like 24 hours wasn't passed, once I waited more time this problem just gone

P.S. only Safari show this, there is no error in Google Chrome

P.P.S sometimes it happens even for successfully processed video but after a page refresh, the problem is gone